# TSQL return all records in-case of null inside IN

Tags: t-sql

I want to filter by @campId if not null, or return all if null

This compiles but does not work as intended:

```
 declare @campId int
 select * 
 from cli 
 where 
    cu in (
        CASE @campId 
          when null then (select id from [dbo].[camp]) 
          else @campId 
        end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if cu is never null

```
where cu = isnull(@campid, cu)
```

Comment: This is very good answer, thx for posting... will be accepting shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from cli
where
   cu in (select  isnull(@campId, id) from [dbo].[camp])
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the select from camp will return @campId if it's not null.

Comment: I like your answer more than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use an `IF` statement?

```
DECLARE @campId AS INT

IF (@campId IS NULL) BEGIN
      SELECT [Column1], [Column2], ...
      FROM [dbo].[cli] AS C1
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Camp] AS C2 ON C2.[Id] = C1.[Cu]  
END
ELSE BEGIN
      SELECT [Column1], [Column2], ...
      FROM [dbo].[cli] AS
      WHERE [Cu] = @camp    
END
```